# Fix for Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError while installing Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby and have installed a couple gems in the past on my Linux virtual machine. However, when I try to install any new gem I get: Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError

Here's the whole error message when I try to install the google-api-client gem with this command:

> gem install -v google-api-client

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
    Illformed requirement ["google-api-client"]

      raise BadRequirementError, "Illformed requirement [#{obj.inspect}]"
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:106:in `parse'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:138:in `block in initialize'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:138:in `map!'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:138:in `initialize'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/version_option.rb:55:in `new'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/version_option.rb:55:in `block in add_version_option'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:583:in `conv_arg'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:738:in `parse'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:1686:in `block in parse_in_order'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:1636:in `catch'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:1636:in `parse_in_order'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:1630:in `order!'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:1739:in `permute!'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/optparse/lib/optparse.rb:1764:in `parse!'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:448:in `handle_options'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:313:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:252:in `invoke_command'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:192:in `process_args'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:150:in `run'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
        /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/gem:10:in `<main>'
```

I researched this question but every answer has to do with an issue in a specific gem. This does the same thing for every gem I try to install.

Answer (score 0):

The [`-v` option](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install) is used with `gem install` when you want to install a specific version of a gem. For example, like this:

```
gem install google-api-client -v 0.53.0
```

But your CLI call misses a version number, therefore, you get that error message.

When you just want to install the latest available version of a gem, then remove the `-v` part and install the gem like this:

```
gem install google-api-client
```